# regular expressions - escape character problem

Tags: escaping, expression

I have thes items:
dv_beh1 
dv_beh2 
dv_beh3 
dv_beh4r
dv_beh5r
dv_beh10
dv_beh11
dv_beh12r
dv_beh13r
dv_beh14r

1. select only items with "r"
   '(^dv_beh_[0-9]+r)'
2. How can I select only items without "r"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like `(^dv_beh[0-9]+$)`

Answer (score 0):

Just check for end of string without matching the `r`.  Try this:

`(^dh_beh[0-9]+$)`